# Windows running 24/7: logged in vs logged off

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, logout, logoff

There are lots of discussions about leaving PC running 24/7 or shutting it down from time to time. This is not what my question is about. My question is about running Windows 24/7, but wondering if it makes any difference if I log off once a week. Does logging off once a week helps Windows in any way? It's running 24/7 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Logging off is not going to make a significant difference. Windows will need to clear certain memory issues, which it can only do on a fresh start (Windows Updates not mentioned).

In Windows 7, shutdown and reboot are the same thing, so either can be used. Logging off will close all programs opened by your user, but not all device drivers and programs that are installed for all users or have parts that run in the background (such as a virusscanner) will also continue to work if you are logged out.

Although it will help, it is not the same as a reboot. Most problems you get from leaving a pc on for a long while are programs and drivers that run as system, not as user.

If you keep the same programs running most of the time, then a log off will force to close these programs but the impact is still nothing compared to all running programs that run as the system user.

Once in a while, you will need to reboot. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Just to prove that being logged in does make any difference, I routinely leave my Windows 10 machine in a logged-in status for weeks, any restarts that do happen are only due to Windows Update.